# How to Get and Print a String Using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, integration

I have a small project that I'm working on (dealing with getting a name and printing it with a string). The problem is that when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type = "css" rel="stylesheet" href = "css.css"/>
        <script>
                var button = document.getElementById('send');
                var enter = document.getElementById('enter');
                    button.onclick function() {
                        var str = 'Hello ' + enter.value + ' how are you?'; 
                    alert(str);
                    }
        </script> 
        <title>HAL 9000 SIM</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id=p1> What is your name? </p>
        <br><br>
        <input type = "text" id="enter" name = "entername"><br>
        <input type = "button" id="send" value="Enter">
</html>
```

It's not complete, as you can probably tell, so any other pointers are greatly needed!

Comment: Take a close look at the syntax for `button.onclick`.  You're missing something...

Comment: You say you are stuck ... please elaborate, because you never describe "the issue at hand"...

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot the "=" sign after the button.click.

Check this:

```
<body>
    <p id=p1>What is your name?</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="enter" name="entername">
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="send" value="Enter">
```

--

```
    var button = document.getElementById('send');
    var enter = document.getElementById('enter');
    button.onclick =
    function () {
        if(enter.value.length > 0)
        {   
            var str = 'Hello ' + enter.value + ' how are you?';
            alert(str);
        }else
        {
            alert("Please input the required fields!");
        }
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pg5k60rz/

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you didnt assign to onclick your function

```js
var enter = document.getElementById('enter');
button.onclick  = function() {
  var str = 'Hello ' + enter.value + ' how are you?'; 
  alert(str);
}
```

secondly if you want your code work, but script before closing body tag